# Função em PHP retornando consulta no banco oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Estou tentando criar uma function no php que traga informações do meu banco de dados Oracle, porém a function não retorna valor algum.
Essa function tem o objetivo retornar alguns dados de usuário.

A função está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
function fn_valida_permissao() {
    include ("../../DataBase/conexao.php");

    $chamado_query = "SELECT pu.idusuario IDUSUARIO
                       FROM usuario u
                      WHERE u.idusuario = upper('usuario_de_acesso')";

    $chamado = oci_parse($ora_conexao, $chamado_query);
    oci_execute($chamado);

    while($v_pagina=oci_fetch($chamado)) {
        return $v_pagina = oci_result($chamado, 'IDUSUARIO');
    }
}
?>
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão de como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, ou você não copiou direito, ou dá pra ver o erro de cara de execução do SQL. Você definiu no `FROM` somente o alias `u`, mas está tentando retornar `pu.idusuario`

Segundo, não precisa de um `while` se tu sabe que só vai retornar um registro ou quer mostrar só um registro. Assim que executar o primeiro `return` ele vai sair da função.

```
while($v_pagina=oci_fetch($chamado)) {

    return $v_pagina = oci_result($chamado, 'IDUSUARIO');

}
```